# How to use text from a cell on SUMIF

Tags: google-sheets

I have a google sheet where in there are few text data in Row "B" which is repeating, and row "C" has a transaction in numbers (qty)..

Using Unique function I have sorted out the list in Row "E".

Now I want to Sum all the transaction using Sumif but getting error if use =E3 instead of "A" in formulae.. what needs to be updated in formulae to use refrence of Cell.. As there are large number of data practically copying each data in formula is not possible..

Please guide...

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try to write it like this:

```
=SUMIF($B$42:$B$51; "="&E42; $C$42:$C$51)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks this worked the way I wanted.. Thanks for quick help.